# compute usig cauchy integral formula, $ \int_\Gamma \frac{dz}{z^2+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

The question is:
$$ \int_\Gamma \frac{dz}{z^2+1}$$
[image]

Here is how i thought, we can divide it into two contour and then deform continuously the inner curve to a circle around $i$ but my problem is here how should i deform the bigger contour around $-i$ i couldn't do that, because we can't pass through singularity, what do you think? any suggestion would be great,

Thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with the residue theorem? Can you compute the winding number of $\Gamma$ with respect to $i$ and $-i$?

Comment: unfortunately not I can only Cauchy integral formula :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read the fine print](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem#Statement) viz. $\oint_\Gamma f(z)dz=2\pi i\sum_{w\in S}\color{blue}{I(\Gamma,\,w)}\color{red}{\operatorname{Res}(f,\,w)}$, with $S$ the set of poles of a holomorphic $f$ the closed rectifiable curve $\Gamma$ encloses, so $w\in S$ has winding number $I(\Gamma,\,w)$. Your contour integral is$$2\pi i\left(\color{blue}{2}\color{red}{\lim_{z\to i}\frac{1}{z+i}}+\color{blue}{1}\color{red}{\lim_{z\to-i}\frac{1}{z-i}}\right)=2\pi i(2/(2i)+1/(-2i))=\pi.$$

Comment: Thanks, my teacher has said to deform the curve into 3 circles two around "i" and one around "-i" but i didn't understand how is that possible?

Comment: @simon You certainly can. The great thing about the residue theorem is you only really need the contour's topology relative to the poles, so even a complicated problem works in terms of counting circles. You can experiment with deformations using string. One that makes the winding numbers obvious is to "pull tight" around the pole at $i$, but this means the circle around $-i$ is one of the circles around $i$. I hope/suspect that's what your teacher had in mind, as the contour only goes through $2$ revolutions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

The result follows from the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) for closed contours.

If you are only allowed to use the Cauchy integral formula with *simple* closed contours, first rewrite the integral as
$$
\int_\Gamma\frac{1}{z^2+1}\,dz=\frac{1}{2i}\left(\int_\Gamma\frac{1}{z-i}dz-\int_\Gamma\frac{1}{z+i}dz\right)
$$

Then after you split the contour $\Gamma$, handle $\frac{1}{z-i}$ and $\frac{1}{z+i}$ separately with the Cauchy integral formula.

Answer (score 1):

The "three curves" solution.  We use three curves.
The first curve surrounds $-i$ but not $i$.  Notice the direction was reversed on the inner loop.
[image: C1]
The second and thrid curves surround $i$ but not $-i$.
[image: C2]

Add the three together to get the original curve.